# Socket Programming in Perl

Tags: perl, sockets, network-programming

I am new to Socket Programming. Here is what I am trying to do:

I would like to transmit a Packet to another Server in the network over an UDP Connection.

Here is the short code snippet I wrote in Perl:

```
# create udp socket
$sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(
  Proto       => "udp",
  PeerPort    => '5001',
  PeerAddr    => defined $ip ? $ip : '10.42.43.2'
) or die "Socket could not be created: $!\n";
```

I would like to handle the exception when the host (10.42.43.2) is not reachable. Any ideas how it can be done ?

Thanks you so much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) is an [unreliable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability_%28computer_networking%29) protocol, which means it doesn't provide a means of finding out if delivery was successful or not.

One option is to switch to a reliable protocol like TCP.

Another is to handle delivery notifications yourself. Have the host send a reply on receipt of your packet. If no reply has been received within X seconds, an error occurred.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried the second approach since changing from tcp to udp would require a lot of design changes. Thanks for your time.